# Partial Fill Models

Tags: 3d-printing

Been trying this for two days, but seems like something is off.

I am working on an easy model, with what I thought would be an easy solution (Still pretty new to blender)

Basically, I am looking to 3D print an object, and there are gaps for the eyes and mouth, I want the model to be completely smooth on the back with the mount and eyes indented on the front

I tried adding a rectangle and joining them, but the lines still show through and my printer also picks up on the inner square.

How do I achieve this where it's all 1 model, and my printer will not pick up on both objects when printing?

[image: I need it to look like the middle image]

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, is the plane seen in the after fill image not connected directly to the mesh? I'm pretty sure it would have to be completely manifold to work.

Comment: it's supposed to be all connected, basically in the end as just one single mesh.Think of it this way, i am basically just trying to partial fill a hole.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe try the boolean modifier set to union?

Comment: Did you select all vertices of the hole's outer edge and inner edge and used F to fill? I usually have the problem that the _Fill_ function is not good at creating faces with a void in it, like on the letter "O" for example (as your hole shape basically looks like, too). It cannot "cut out" the inner area. What you can do instead is select all vertices on the left half for example, fill the left side of the hole, then repeat it for the right side. This way you get the hole filled with two faces instead of one, not an "O" but a "C" and a mirrored "C" connected to each other.